# Show next part of text in TextBlock

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

[image]

I set MaxLines on TextBlock and I would to after click on it to firstly clear actual text and next show next part of text in this TextBlock.

```
 <TextBlock
      MaxLines="3"
      Name="DescriptionText" 
      Grid.Row="1" 
      Grid.Column="1" 
      FontWeight="Thin"
      Foreground="White"
      FontSize="18"
      TextWrapping="Wrap"
      TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"
      Tapped = "DescriptionText_Tapped"/>
```

This event should change parts of text in this TextBlock with no changing it's Height.

Comment: Why don't you use `ScrollViewer`?

Comment: You can declare globaly a string array lines, put in lines the different parts of the text, declare a variable int index=0; and in DescriptionText_Tapped add 1 to index modulo the number of lines: index = (index + 1) % lines.Length; and modify the text: DescriptionText.Text=lines[index];